# JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application --> Getting this error eventhough main method is there

Tags: java

JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application --> Getting this error eventhough main method is there.

Please refer to my sample code:

```
package testpkg;

class Overloading1 {
public void disp(char c) {
    System.out.println(c);
}

public void disp(char c, int num) {
    System.out.println(c + " " + num);
}

}

class Overloading2 extends Overloading1 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Overloading2 obj = new Overloading2();
    obj.disp('a');
    obj.disp('a', 10);
}
```

}

Comment: is that all in an Overloading1.java file? also: what has any of this got to do with JavaFX?

Comment: Yes all that code written in Overloading1.java file.

Comment: why would you put a main method in a non-public class?

Comment: If i make Overloading2 class as public, then i am getting following error,        
The public type Overloading2 must be defined in its own file

Comment: So ... you are struggling with the basics of java, yet you have started a JavaFX project?

Comment: Ya. Thanks for your feedback. I am in a beginner in Java. I just renamed the .java file as "Overloading2.java" and now code is getting executed without any error. Once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the normal java application has a main class with as entry point `public static void main(String[] args)`.

However you created a JavaFX project, which by definitions puts its application code in a JavaFX specific Application class which your main class has to extend. The IDE tries to start a JavaFX application.

If you want to have the JavaFX GUI application, study a tutorial.

Otherwise create a normal java application project. (Which seems to be the case here.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your IDE project is set up wrongly as "JavaFx Application". 
Most IDEs call the normal java project type "Empty Project" or "Java Project".

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be a Javafx issue.
Create Separate files for both Classes with name Overloading1.java and Overloading2.java :

Overloading1.java :

```
class Overloading1 {
    public void disp(char c) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public void disp(char c, int num) {
        System.out.println(c + " " + num);
    }

}
```

And Overloading2.java :

```
class Overloading2 extends Overloading1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Overloading2 obj = new Overloading2();
        obj.disp('a');
        obj.disp('a', 10);
    }
}
```

And try to run the Overloading2.java again. If still you are facing issue, check your launcher or environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project is build successfully.  If you are using eclipse, Check "Marker tab" for any error and fix.